# Div Going Down for Some Reason?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got text to the left and a div to the right. The div won't sit next to the text: it always gets pushed below. I've tried setting the div/text to display: block and display: inline-block, neither of which worked. I've also tried setting the text to float: left and clear: both, and that just messed EVERYTHING up. Ideas?

```js
var x = 0;
var body = document.getElementById("x");

window.onload = change;

function change() {
  setTimeout(color, 500);
}

function color() {
  body.style.background = "hsl(" + x + ", 100%, 50%)";
  if (x < 358) {
    x++;
    setTimeout(color, 500);
  } else {
    x = 0;
    setTimeout(color, 500);
  }
}
```

```css
#x {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
#title {
  font-family: Poiret One, sans;
  color: white;
  font-size: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#desc {
  font-family: Poiret One, sans;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#desc2 {
  font-family: Poiret One, sans;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#sub {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="x">
  <p id="title">Net99</p>
  <p id="desc">Hello. Here's some text. You like it? Good.</p>
  <p id="desc2">Here's some more text. Nice, right?</p>
  <div id="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to put the float:right div first.

```
<div id="x">
  <div id="sub"></div>
  <p id="title">Net99</p>
  <p id="desc">Hello. Here's some text. You like it? Good.</p>
  <p id="desc2">Here's some more text. Nice, right?</p>
  <!-- used to be here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try floating `#title`, and displaying the descriptions as blocks:

```css
#title {
    float: left;
}
#desc, #desc2 {
    display: block; /* Default value */
}
```

```js
var x = 0;
var body = document.getElementById("x");

window.onload = change;

function change() {
  setTimeout(color, 500);
}

function color() {
  body.style.background = "hsl(" + x + ", 100%, 50%)";
  if (x < 358) {
    x++;
    setTimeout(color, 500);
  } else {
    x = 0;
    setTimeout(color, 500);
  }
}
```

```css
#x {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
#title {
  font-family: Poiret One, sans;
  color: white;
  font-size: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
#desc {
  font-family: Poiret One, sans;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
#desc2 {
  font-family: Poiret One, sans;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
#sub {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="x">
  <p id="title">Net99</p>
  <p id="desc">Hello. Here's some text. You like it? Good.</p>
  <p id="desc2">Here's some more text. Nice, right?</p>
  <div id="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This kind of worked. The problem now is the descriptions are pushing it down. I tried floating them too, and that just didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following:

```
#sub {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktxxsr1g/)